# singly and doubly linked list in java?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

Which collection interface is efficient to implement the singly and doubly linked list in java? code sample please?

Comment: Please check this out .
[http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/collections/lists/simple-linked-list.html](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/collections/lists/simple-linked-list.html)

Answer (score 1):

The right interface to implement a doubly-linked list is, unsurprisingly, a LinkedList.  See [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

I'm not going to give you a code sample here; they're all over the web and you could find one with two minutes' research.

If you want a singly-linked list for some reason, you're probably going to have to roll your own using a custom Node class.  Each Node should just have a data object and a pointer to the next Node.